# How can you suppress the blue or green channels of an image on Android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to make a stereoscopic 3-D image in an Android application. For this, I will need to remove the blue or green channels of an image.

How can I do this on Android?

Comment: What have you tried?  How far have you got - do you have an image?  How is it represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you have an image represented as an Android `Bitmap` object.  To "disable" a colour channel you simply set the pixel value for than channel to zero, which means it no longer contributes to the image.  Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ... //Assuming you have a bitmap somehow
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitmap.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000);
    }
}
```

The crucial part to understand here is that bitmap colours here are represented by a four-byte integer; the first byte is the alpha (transparency) value, the second byte is the red channel value, the third is green and the fourth is blue.  The hex value `0xFFFF0000` therefore means "maximum alpha" (since `FF` is the largest byte value), "maximum red", "zero green" and "zero blue".

I then perform a [*bitwise AND*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) operation with the **old** pixel value, using `0xFFFF0000` as my mask, using the `&` operator.  This basically "selects" the red values and ignores the blue and green, giving a **new** pixel value containing just the red channel.

You can do a similar thing with the other channels; if you want just the blue channel, which you probably will if you're making an anaglyph image, you can use the mask `0xFF0000FF`, and if you just wanted the green channel you could use `0xFF00FF00`.

BTW, I'm not entirely sure this is the best way to create a anaglyph image, but it might still work - nonetheless this is the answer to your actual question :)

Comment: Sir Great thanks for help .Sorry sir but i need more help . Sir if i have to set alpha and red of new image equals to alpha and red of older image , how can i do it. 
. Thanks to you sir

Comment: I don't understand your question.  My answer explains how to set the alpha and red values of the new image to that of the old image.  What are you asking now?

Comment: i mean to say the newely created bitmap shoud have alpha and red channel same as the original bitmap

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say it: *that's exactly what this code will do*.

Comment: It works well but is there any faster way to do this?